# Recurse over a object - Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

Suppose I have the following object:

```
var my_obj = {
    x: 0,
    y: [Object]
}
```

every time I call the function `recurse_object` I will add another element to `my_obj`, and create a recursive object:

```
function recurse_object(my_obj) {
   if ("top" in my_obj) {
      var x = my_obj;
      my_obj = { top: x };
   } else {
     // missing test case. 
   }
   return my_obj;
}
```

so that after the first call `my_obj` will look like:

```
var my_obj = {
    top: { 
       x: 0,
       y: [Object]
    }
}
```

A second call to `recurse_object` will have `my_obj` looking like:

```
   var my_obj = {
      top: {
        top: { 
           x: 0,
           y1: [Object1]
        },
        x: 1,
        y2: [Object2]
      }
    }
```

the value of `x` and `y` in the `my_obj` will change. A new property `y2` may be added. Thus, I will take the current `my_obj` and place it into `top`, and copy the new elements to the `"new"` `my_obj`.
How can I accomplish that in JS?

Comment: _"will add another element to foo, and create a recursive object:"_ `foo` not appear as defined object or variable at `js` at Question ?

Comment: from the description of your objective, it looks like the `else` case should be identical to the `if` case, in other words, you don't need the conditional to check if `top` is in `my_obj`

Comment: I think you just want `function f(o) { return { top: o }; }` and `my_obj = f(my_obj)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function seems a little odd. If I understood your question corectly, the answer maybe something like this

```
function recurse_object(obj) {

    var key='top';
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
       //here we change the y
       var keys = Object.keys(obj.top);
       var count='';
       var currentCount='';
       //go through all keys to find y because we don't know exact name
       for(var k in keys){
          if(k.indexOf('y')==0){
              currentCount=k.substring(1);
              if(currentCount!='')
                 count=parseInt(currentCount)+1;
              else 
                 count=1; 
          }
       }
       var x=obj;
       obj['y'+count]=obj.['y'+currentCount];
       delete obj.['y'+currentCount];
       obj.top=x;
    }
    else{
       obj.top=obj;
    }
 }
```

Comment: It was close. However I meant by `y0` and `y1` they are totally different properties of `obj`. Let's say `obj` got extended somehow with those two new properties.

Comment: so you keep recursing with new properties? also y0 isn't in your question

Comment: @philippe consider upvoting/accepting the answer if it helped you